# "No such file" error trying to get modification time for symlink

Tags: python

I am trying to get the modification time of files on my hard drive. The code looks like this:

```
mtime = int(os.path.getmtime(path))
```

However, I keep running into this strange error:

```
File "./import.py", line 67, in find
  mtime = int(os.path.getmtime(path))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 62, in getmtime
  return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/RunningChromeVersion'
```

This is strange because the item does exist; its a symlink to the version of Chrome that is installed:

```
$ ll '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/RunningChromeVersion'
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 username  staff    13B Jan 12 16:58 /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/RunningChromeVersion -> 79.0.3945.117
```

Notably, it indeed has a modification time; `Jan 12 16:58`

However, if you get the absolute path, it looks like this:

```
$ greadlink -f '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/RunningChromeVersion'
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/79.0.3945.117
```

and if you check, that target does not actually exist;

```
$ ll '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/79.0.3945.117'
ls: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/79.0.3945.117: No such file or directory
```

What I do not understand, is why is Python not returning the modification time of the symlink, the path its actually being given? Why does this cause an error at all? Obviously `ls` is able to see the modification time, so why cant Python figure it out?

Comment: To avoid needing to ask questions like this in the future, you could compare `strace` from the `ls` call and the Python code, to see how the syscalls they're using differ.

Answer (score 2):

To get stat data on the link itself rather than its target, use `os.lstat()` rather than `os.stat()`.

Comment: so `os.path.getmtime` seems to just be a wrapper around `os.stat` then?